# Return all dates that do not have a matching entry

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've tried some of the other solutions I've found on SO, but they don't seem to work with my schema, or I just suck at SQL. So let's say I have two tables, table 1 is something like this:

```
LastName | FirstName | Date

Doe        John        7/07/14
Doe        John        7/07/14
Doe        John        7/08/14
Bond       James       7/07/14
Bond       James       7/09/14
Jane       Mary        7/08/14
```

Essentially, a person will have an entry for a certain date. they can also have multiple entries for one date. table 2 is a range of dates, such as:

```
Date
7/06/14
7/07/14
7/08/14
7/09/14
```

What I want to do is get a result set that shows for what days in table 2 is a person missing an entry, ideally with the person's name as well. Any leads? Thanks!

Comment: select from YourDateTable left join to TableWithData on date = date. You may need to get a list of names too...of course it would be better if you normalized that anyway.

Comment: So for John Doe, you would show 7/06/14, because he doesn't have a record for that date?

Comment: John Doe would have 7/06/14 and 7/09/14 since he doesn't have one for either of those, but yeah the idea is to show the missing dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  --create list of all names and date combinations from both table
  SELECT DISTINCT A.LastName, A.FirstName, B.Date_col
  FROM Table1 A, Table2 B
)
--select rows that are missing dates in your first table
SELECT X.* FROM CTE X
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 Y 
    ON X.LastName = Y.LastName 
    AND X.FirstName = Y.FirstName 
    AND X.Date_col = Y.Date_Col
WHERE Y.LastName IS NULL
```

Comment: Should `AND X.Date_col = B.Date_Col` be `AND X.Date_col = Y.Date_Col`. +1 good solution.

Comment: Just tried this, looks like it's the winner, thanks!

Comment: @JChao, yes you are right, that was typo. I fixed it.